# MySQL Join Comma Separated Field

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. First Table is a `batch` table that contain comma separated student id in field "batch"

```
batch
--------------
id      batch 
--------------
1       1,2     
2       3,4
```

Second Table is marks

```
marks
----------------------
id  studentid   subject     marks
1     1         English     50
2     2         English     40
3     3         English     70
4     1         Math        65
5     4         English     66
6     5         English     75
7     2         Math        55
```

How we can find those students of first batch id =1 who have scored more than 45 marks in English without using sub query.

Problem i found to get this done using a single query is that we can not use **IN** as an association operator in JOIN statement

What changes are required in below query to make it work?

```
SELECT * FROM batch
INNER JOIN marks ON marks.studentid IN(batch.batch) where batch.id = 1
```

Comment: sounds like homework - if so, please tag it as "homework", too.

Comment: @oezi :), You can say like that but my question is to use comma separated field in a join. But i don't want to use sub query to get the records.

Comment: fyi, this practice was deemed as an anti-pattern. Please use sparingly http://www.scribd.com/doc/2670985/SQL-Antipatterns

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.studentId
FROM    batch b
JOIN    marks m
ON      FIND_IN_SET(m.studentId, b.batch)
        AND m.subject = 'English'
GROUP BY
        m.studentId
HAVING  SUM(marks) > 45
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! It worked for me with little difference that group by and having was not required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the proper solution is to refactor the student-batch relation. Why not add a foreign key to the "batch" table to the "student" table. Students 1 and 2 would refer batch 1, students 3 and 4 would refer batch 2.

Comment: I can not do that as this is a production database table of my maintenance project. But got solution (provided by Quassnoi) in the above thread

Comment: I understand the difficulty of migrating a production database, but there are tools. I would consider a tool for schema and data migrations a must in any database-centered application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store two values in one database field - you violate [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and you are [going to have a bad time](http://qkme.me/3pl8b2) when you try to use SQL to analyse the data.

I can't entirely understand what you are getting at in your problem description with the different ids - but I think you will want the batch table to be more like:

```
batch
--------------
id      batch 
--------------
1       1
1       2     
2       3
2       4
```

Comment: Actually i got this table relationship from one of our maintenance project so i can not really make changes in database to achieve First Normal Form. But anyways.. i have got solution provided by Quassnoi in the above thread